# Is the length of the longest balanced parentheses in )()(())()()))())))( 10 and not 12?

Tags: algorithms

In Skiena, S.: *The Algorithm Design Manual* 3rd Ed., Exercise 3.2 reads as follows

> Give an algorithm that takes a string $S$ consisting of opening and closing parentheses, say )()(())()()))())))(, and finds the length of the longest balanced parentheses in $S$, which **is 12 in the example above**.
> (Hint: The solution is not necessarily a contiguous run of parenthesis from $S$.)

I don't understand how its 12. Wouldn't it be 10? Ive bolded below what I believe to be the longest balanced parentheses.

)**()(())()()**))())))(

Comment: I guess you have to follow the *hint* to the extent of ignoring some of the text of Ex. 3.1: *A common problem for compilers and text editors is determining whether the parentheses in a string are balanced and properly nested. For example, the string $( ( ( ) ) ( ) ) ( )$ contains properly nested pairs of parentheses, which the strings $) ( ) ($ and $( ) )$ do not. Give an algorithm that returns true if a string contains [consists exclusively of?!] properly nested and balanced parentheses, and false if otherwise.*

Comment: (Relevant or not, *3.2* does *not* explicitly require *properly nested*: `)()(())()()()(` is a longish balanced [subsequence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) of the string specified as is `)()(())()(())(`.)

Comment: The problem states "not necessarily a contiguous run". That means we can add a pair of parentheses that are not immediately next to the earlier sequence:  ) **( ) ( ( ) ) ( ) ( )** ) ) **( )** ) ) ) (